# Можно ли в данном контексте оставить мн. ч.: "свидетельствуют"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

> В великом молчаливом действе церкви Святой Пракседы участвуют не
>   только двадцать четыре  апокалиптических старца в белых одеждах,
>   которые простирают к Иисусу венки: *И я взглянул, и вот, посреди
>   престола и четырех животных и посреди старцев стоял Агнец как бы
>   закланный*. Этому видению Жертвы **свидетельствуют весь род
>   человеческий, ангельский и небесный**.

Comment: По-моему, что-то здесь не то. Род человеческий -- да, существует. Но нет рода ангельского и нет рода небесного. Можно было бы сказать: _Этому видению Жертвы свидетельствует весь род человеческий, ангелы и Небеса_. Но смысла в этой фразе я не вижу.

Comment: Слава, спасибо огромное! А почему не ответом - ЛОшечку дам! )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этому видению Жертвы **свидетельствует**  (весь) род человеческий, ангельский и небесный.

Препозитивное сказуемое, форма ед. числа.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)